# Какие существуют способы организации поиска паттернов проектирования (GOF) в исходном коде?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет.

Возникла идея заняться решением задачи по поиску паттернов проектирования в исходном коде, написанном на C#. Собственно, после изучения данной области и всего, с чем мне придется столкнуться, я выделил 3 уровня реализации паттернов:

1. "общая реализация", когда программист сам создает классы, объекты, определяет иерархию наследования, отношения между объектами и т.д. То есть по сути реализует паттерн "с нуля". Поиск таких паттернов будет организован с учетом возможных вариантов их реализаций.
2. глубоко интегрированные в .NET паттерны, к примеру, не секрет, что Observer в .NET реализуют события и делегаты.
3. использование классов из BCL. Например, чтобы реализовать "Прототип", можно реализовать интерфейс IClonable. Для реализации "Итератора" нужно реализовать интерфейсы IEnumerable и IEnumerator и т.д.

Вопрос в том, достаточно ли учесть эти три уровня реализации паттернов проектирования для организации успешного их поиска, или нужно учесть еще какие-нибудь возможные варианты? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, ваша задача, если решать её по-настоящему, на грани искусственного интеллекта. Тот же итератор вполне можно реализовать без IEnumerable, вручную. Как вы отличите унарный оператор от реализации клонирования? Вы собираетесь анализировать исходный код? Тогда вам придётся решить, например, [проблему остановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Comment: Проблема написать, например, нейронную сеть в том, что нужна большая выборка примеров и контрпримеров и будет проблемно создать для каждого паттерна около 1000 различных реализаций... 
Это 23000 исходников (если реализовывать поиск 23 шаблонов GOF)...
А можно про унарный оператор поподробнее?)

Comment: Ну, нейтронная сеть даст приблизительный, а не точный результат. Вам точно не нужно? А унарный оператор (например, минус) по сигнатуре ничем не отличается от операции клонирования. И там и там `class C { public C F() { ... } }`.

Comment: Это при перегрузке операторов? Ну тогда отличить просто, в перегрузке должен использоваться static метод

Comment: это почему это должен использоваться статик меотд?

Comment: Если речь идет об операторных методах, то они должны быть объявлены как public static... Но как я понимаю, речь шла не о перегрузке

Comment: На хабре, как-то, за пару недель было с 10-к статей по тому, как правильно реализовывать паттерн «мост». Я это к чему: патерны могут быть реализованы по-разному, они — всего лишь идея. Ваша задача не имеет смысла, даже человек не может паттерны в коде найти, зачастую.

Comment: Можно ведь учесть разные реализации, если не все, то как можно больше. Можно, кстати, линк на статьи?)

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy: Ну никто же не мешает объявить его просто как нестатическую функцию `Negate`.

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy может быть немного странный вопрос - зачем именно вы хотите искать паттерны в коде? Я к тому, что паттерны - это типовые проблемы + типовые решения. Проблема итерации возникает в каждом втором методе. События тоже используются активно. Композит, например - вообще из каждого LINQ запроса лезет. Т.е. вы получите десяток используемых паттернов даже в небольшом куске кода. Что вы собираетесь делать с полученной информацией об использовании? :)

Comment: @PashaPash ну во первых интерес такой - проанализировать множество проектов и понять, какие паттерны используются чаще, какие реже, во вторых это может быть полезно при ознакомлении программиста с уже написанным кодом, т.е. зная, какие паттерны использованы, можно иметь некоторое представление об архитектуре системы, даже не открывая исходники

Comment: _зная, какие паттерны использованы, можно иметь некоторое представление об архитектуре системы, даже не открывая исходники_ - очень сомнительно, что по наличию/отсутствию паттернов, можно иметь представление об архитектуре.

Comment: @Grundy По меньшей мере разработчик будет знать, с чем ему придется иметь дело. По моему очень удобно, к примеру, узнать, какие фабрики есть, какие продукты они создают, какие классы декорируются, какие интерфейсы адаптируются, что должно иметь лишь один объект, а что должно объявлять интерфейс для клонирования, где есть разделение абстракции от реализации, а где реализована древовидная структура. А если в проекте классам даны хорошие имена, то вообще здорово, т.к. можно понять логику происходящего.